# Keeping track of outgoing emails from any .NET application

Tags: c#, email, profiler, mcafee

I have windows 2003 server with about 15 C# windows services sending emails randomly based on some complex business logic. It is a very difficult to find out which application sending emails to whom at what time.

For additional info, the server has McAfee client installed and configured by admin that which application can send emails.

Is there any way I can find out which application is sending email to whom?

Comment: I have several applications that do email alerts, and store the emails from each application in a separate database table. Is this plausible for you?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get your question.

Comment: If you store each application's email information (ids etc) in a separate database table you will know who sent what.

Comment: No, the issue is there are thousands of email ids in database and it is not possible to keep track of who's receiver of emails.

Comment: Why are you storing email ids? What are you storing along with them? When do they get stored?

Comment: We are not storing any email ids, it's into employee database and out of scope of any application.

Comment: "Most of the email ids are stored in database." please edit your question to be more clear. Perhaps you should start storing records of your sent emails in a database if you need to keep track of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't store the information required in a database, then generate log files specific to your need.  I'm certain you don't need code to tell you how to have your C# services generate log files that contain all the pertinent information (date/time, service name, email address, type/id or some content identifier).  You can then use the logs to generate whatever reporting you need, and if build with configuration, you can turn off the logging once you have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: The issue is I cannot make changes in all the applications as it is a  big task and out of scope too. I am expecting some way like profiler do... I believe McAfee also does this but don't know how to keep track of all outgoing emails from application/machine using McAfee server.